# Poset where every Upper Set has a Greatest Element

Tags: ct.category-theory, terminology, order-theory

Does anyone know of a term for (equivalently)

1. A preorder $P$ where for every $x \in P$ there exists $x_\top \ge x$ such that for any $y \ge x $, $x_\top \ge y $.
2. A preorder $P$ where for every $x \in P$, $\uparrow x$ has a greatest element?

for categories this would be a category $C$ where for every object $x$ the coslice $x\backslash C$ has a terminal object or dually every slice has an initial object.

In my applications the preorders/categories involved do *not* have a global greatest element, just the upper sets/coslices.

My only idea is to call these posets "locally bounded".

Comment: Or equivalently, $P$ decomposes into a disjoint union of mutually incomparable posets, each of which has a greatest element?

Comment: So it is a exactly a disjoint sum of bounded-above pre-orders.

Comment: Finished the first condition. Can't believe I didn't realize it makes them into a disjoint sum. Makes perfect sense in my application too.